# Using Attributes for registering callbacks?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

The result I'm trying to get it something like this:

```
// The DLL containing this would be loaded by another C# Dll, the moment it's registered
// it'd gets invoked by the main DLL when that event occurs
[Callback("someevent")]
void SomeMethod() { }
```

I don't know how it'd be possible to access the method from an attribute, or if there's a function that gets called every time a method with an attribute gets instantiated.

There's two instances of something like this / something similar being done, DllImport and [S&box's event system](https://wiki.facepunch.com/sbox/EventSystem)
, though I tried looking at their source code and I can't see / understand how they did it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the attribute contains the name of the callback, you'd have to use reflection to find the method on the class. You could also do the reverse and use an attribute to say "this method is the callback to this method". But there's no way to do it automatically, attributes have no knowledge of the thing they are attached to, only the type system does.

Comment: The sbox event system probably works because they create an instance of your class, then use reflection to figure out which method to call in a particular scenario.